# shell variable in awk is not being passed to all the lines but just for the very first line of input?

Tags: linux, shell-script, awk, variable-substitution, variable

inputfile:**is2.txt**

```
10.39.5.41,A1,B1
10.39.5.41,A2,B2
10.39.5.41,A3,B3
10.39.5.41,A4,B4
10.39.5.41,A5,B5
10.39.5.41,A6,B6
```

script :

```
#!/bin/bash
second_column="OOOOOOO"    # OOOOOOO will be added to every second column
third_column="XXXXXXXX"    # XXXXXXXX will be added to every third column

awk -v second="$second_column" -v third="$third_column" 'BEGIN { FS="," }
                             {
                                if(a[$1])
                                {a[$1]=a[$1]";second"$2";third"$3}
                                 else
                                {a[$1]=a[$1]second$2";"third$3}}
                             END{for (i in a)print i";"a[i];}' <  is2.txt

output:
[root@testgfs2 test]# ./testawk.awk
10.39.5.41;OOOOOOOA1;XXXXXXXXB1;secondA2;thirdB2;secondA3;thirdB3;secondA4;thirdB4;secondA5;thirdB5;secondA6;thirdB6
```

why the shell variables (second_column, third_column) are not being reflected for the complete output and just for the first line. What's wrong?

expected output:

```
10.39.5.41;OOOOOOOA1;XXXXXXXXB1;OOOOOOOA2;XXXXXXXXB2;OOOOOOOA3;XXXXXXXXB3;OOOOOOOA4;XXXXXXXXB4;OOOOOOOA5;XXXXXXXXB5;OOOOOOOA6;XXXXXXXXB6
```

Moreover, is there any way to generalize this for n number of columns say n = 100?

Comment: It's much easier to just use `sed(1)` to do this replacement. BTW, in your '-quoted script, the shell variables won't be interpolated at all.

Comment: can you show me then, and what if the ist columns had differnt inputs and i wanted the data to be organized for each value of the first column somehting like `10.10.10.10;OOOOOOOA1;XXXXXXXXB1;OOOOOOOA2;XXXXXXXXB2;OOOOOOOA3;XXXXXXXXB3` and on the onther line `20.20.20.20;OOOOOOOA1;XXXXXXXXB1;OOOOOOOA2;XXXXXXXXB2;OOOOOOOA3;XXXXXXXXB3` and how would i generalize it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's the awk code with recommended spacing and indention, can you see the problem?

```awk
BEGIN { FS = "," }

{
  if(a[$1])
    a[$1] = a[$1] ";second" $2 ";third" $3
  else
    a[$1] = a[$1]second $2 ";" third$3
}

END {
  for (i in a)
    print i ";" a[i]
}
```

You quoted `second` and `third` in the `if` clause.

Guessing from your expected output, you could do it like this:

```
awk -v c2='OOOOOOO' -v c3='XXXXXXXX' -v FS=, -v OFS=';' -v ORS=';' '
  !f { 
    printf "%s", $1
    f=1
  } 
  {
    $1 = ""
    $2 = c2 $2
    $3 = c3 $3
  } 
  1
' | sed 's/;;/;/g; s/;$//'
```

Output:

```
10.39.5.41;OOOOOOOA1;XXXXXXXXB1;OOOOOOOA2;XXXXXXXXB2;OOOOOOOA3;XXXXXXXXB3;OOOOOOOA4;XXXXXXXXB4;OOOOOOOA5;XXXXXXXXB5;OOOOOOOA6;XXXXXXXXB6
```

To generalize this approach, you could pass in the bits to prepend through a string and split it into an awk array. Then use a for-loop instead of explicit column variables:

```
awk -v prepends='OOOOOOO XXXXXXXX' -v FS=, -v OFS=';' -v ORS=';' '
  BEGIN { split(prepends, cn, / +/) } 

  !f { 
    printf "%s", $1
    f=1
  } 

  { 
    $1 = ""
    for(i=1; i<=NF; i++) 
      $i = cn[i-1] $i
  }
  1' | sed 's/;;/;/g; s/;$//'
```